# Another domain is pointing to my server and serving my site in its place

Tags: nginx, server

We have recently moved to Laravel Forge and purchased a Digital Ocean droplet. We were ready to go live with the site, however we have spotted a total duplicate domain of ours. This domain looks like it's routing through our server to then show our site.

I have tried creating a new site block as per below :

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;
return 444;
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to have blocked it either. I'm a bit of a novice with nginx, so found that answer via a google search. I've rebooted Nginx and had no luck.

I didn't know or think that a user could just simply point their domain to your domain and your site be served. Seems like a security issue to me. Is there any other Nginx or Forge methods that I can use to prevent this from happening?

Worth also pointing out, we are using Laravel to make the website, so we could also look at a middleware route?

Any help much appreciated, as my MD is panicking now and give me hassle, ha!

Thanks

Comment: The other domain can be simply acting as a proxy to your site - the only practical thing for you is to ban the IP of their server.

Comment: What do you see in the access log, what IP address is connecting to your site?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that IP address. Nice idea to do that, is it possible that Digital Ocean have given us the same IP of an old site?